# Bounce animation is working only after second tap [SwiftUI]

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-animation

I am triggering animation after unhiding the view unfortunately animation is not working unless I tap twice

```
   struct ContentView: View {

    @State var animate = false
    @State var isViewHidden: Bool = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                    Circle()
                        .fill(.blue).opacity(0.25).frame(width: 40, height: 40).offset(y: self.animate ? 0 : 60)
                        .hides(isViewHidden)
                }
                .animation((Animation.linear(duration: 1.5).repeatForever(autoreverses: true))
                           , value: self.animate ? 0 : 60)
            Spacer()
            Button("Tap here") {
                self.isViewHidden = false
                self.animate.toggle()
            }
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func hides(_ isHidden: Bool) -> some View {
        if isHidden {
            hidden()
        } else {
            self
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SwiftUI uses a *before view* and an *after view* to animate.  You are introducing the view to animate at the same time you are updating `self.animate`, so Swift doesn't have a *before view* to use for the animation.

Change your View extension to this:

```
extension View {
    @ViewBuilder
    func hides(_ isHidden: Bool) -> some View {
        self.opacity(isHidden ? 0 : 1)
    }
}
```

This leaves the view onscreen at all times, but just hides it by making it invisible.  That way, the view is there to animate from the start.

Comment: facing this issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74846458/changing-position-of-image-or-view-during-animation-is-not-working-as-expected-i