# changing position of image or view during animation is not working as expected in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, swiftui-animation

I am trying to build walkthrough pop up tip and i want to change of pop up position once the user move to next walkthrough pop up tip. Unfortunately, changing or adding new image or view in current animation view is not working as expected. Newly added image or change in position will make the view get detached from parent view. I tried delay, it worked in Xcode 13 but in Xcode 14 it is not working.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFbuc.gif

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var walkthroughs: [Walkthrough] = Walkthrough.allCases
    @State var currentIndex = 0
    @State var bounceAnimation: Bool = true

    var body: some View {

        ZStack {
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                popTipView(with: walkthroughs[currentIndex])
            }
            VStack {
                Spacer()
                Button("Tap here") {
                        currentIndex += 1
                            withAnimation(.linear(duration: 1.5).repeatForever(autoreverses: true)) {
                                self.bounceAnimation.toggle()
                            }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func popTipView(with currentWalkthrough: Walkthrough) -> some View {
        PopTipSwiftUI(walkThrough: currentWalkthrough)
            .offset(x: currentWalkthrough.position.x,
                    y: bounceAnimation ? currentWalkthrough.position.y : currentWalkthrough.position.y - 8)
    }
}


enum Walkthrough: CaseIterable {
    case first
    case second
    case third
    case fourth
    case fifth
    
    var position: CGPoint {
        switch self {
        case .first:
            return CGPoint(x: 0, y: -200)
        case .second:
            return CGPoint(x: 0, y: 100)
        case .third:
            return CGPoint(x: -20, y: 200)
        case .fourth:
            return CGPoint(x: -20, y: 50)
        case .fifth:
            return CGPoint(x: -20, y: 250)

        }
    }
    var alignment: PopTipAlignment {
        switch self {
        case .first:
            return .topLeft
        case .second:
            return .topRight
        case .third:
            return .bottomCenter
        case .fourth:
            return .topLeft
        case .fifth:
            return .topCenter
        }
    }
    
    var message: String {
        return "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry."
    }
    
    var leftImage: String? {
        switch self {
        case .third:
            return "eye.slash"
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}

enum PopTipAlignment {
    case topLeft
    case topRight
    case topCenter
    case bottomCenter
    case bottomLeft
    case bottomRight
    
    var horizontalAlignment: SwiftUI.HorizontalAlignment {
        switch self {
            case .topLeft, .bottomLeft:
                return .leading
            case .topCenter, .bottomCenter:
                return .center
            default:
                return .trailing
        }
    }

    var offSet: CGFloat {
        switch self {
            case .topLeft, .bottomLeft:
                return 24
            case .topCenter, .bottomCenter:
                return 0
            default:
                return -16
        }
    }
}


struct PopTipSwiftUI: View {
    
    // MARK: Public APIs
    var walkThrough: Walkthrough = .first
    
    // MARK: Private properties
    private var alignment: PopTipAlignment {
        walkThrough.alignment
    }
    
    // MARK: Initialiser
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: walkThrough.alignment.horizontalAlignment, spacing: -Constant.spacing) {
            if alignment == .topLeft || alignment == .topCenter || alignment == .topRight {
                triangularPointer
            }
            textContainerView
            if alignment == .bottomLeft || alignment == .bottomCenter || alignment == .bottomRight {
                triangularPointer
                    .rotationEffect(.radians(.pi))

            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: Constant.maxWidth)
        .background(Color.clear)
    }
    
    // MARK: UI setup
    private var textContainerView: some View {
        HStack(alignment: .center) {
            horizontalSpacerView
            VStack {
                verticalSpacerView
                textView
                verticalSpacerView
            }
            horizontalSpacerView
        }
        .background(Color.black.opacity(Constant.bgOpacity))
        .cornerRadius(Constant.cornerRadius)
    }
    
    private var textView: some View {
        HStack(spacing: Constant.textViewSpacing) {
            leftImage
            Text(walkThrough.message)
                .font(.subheadline)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.leading)
                .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                rightChevronContainerView
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: UI components
    @ViewBuilder
    private var leftImage: some View {
        if let leftImage = walkThrough.leftImage {
            VStack {
                Image(systemName: leftImage)
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: Constant.leftImageWidth, height: Constant.leftImageHeight)
            }
            .frame(width: Constant.leftImageWidth, height: Constant.leftImageHeight)
        } else {
            EmptyView()
        }

    }
    
    private var rightChevronContainerView: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            Image(systemName: "chevron.right")
                .resizable()
                .frame(width: Constant.chevronWidth, height: Constant.chevronHeight)
                .foregroundColor(Color.green)
        }
        .frame(width: Constant.chevronContainerWidth, height: Constant.chevronContainerHeight)
        .background(Color.black.opacity(Constant.chevronContainerOpacity))
        .cornerRadius(Constant.chevronContainerRadius)
    }
    
    private var triangularPointer: some View {
        VStack {
            Triangle()
                .fill(Color.black.opacity(Constant.bgOpacity))
        }
        .frame(width: Constant.triangleSize, height: Constant.triangleSize)
        .offset(x: alignment.offSet)
    }
    
    private var horizontalSpacerView: some View {
        Spacer()
            .frame(width: Constant.spacerWidth)
    }
    
    private var verticalSpacerView: some View {
        Spacer()
            .frame(height: Constant.spacerHeight)
    }
    
    // MARK: Constants
    private enum Constant {
        static let spacerHeight: CGFloat = 20
        static let spacerWidth: CGFloat = 20
        static let cornerRadius: CGFloat = 19
        static let bgOpacity: CGFloat = 0.80
        static let maxWidth: CGFloat = 300
        static let spacing: CGFloat = 0.5
        static let triangleSize: CGFloat = 8
        static let chevronWidth: CGFloat = 4
        static let chevronHeight: CGFloat = 8
        static let chevronContainerHeight: CGFloat = 28
        static let chevronContainerWidth: CGFloat = 40
        static let chevronContainerOpacity: CGFloat = 0.85
        static let chevronContainerRadius: CGFloat = 19
        static let leftImageWidth: CGFloat = 40
        static let leftImageHeight: CGFloat = 28
        static let textViewSpacing: CGFloat = 8
    }
}

struct Triangle: Shape {
    func path(in rect: CGRect) -> Path {
        var path = Path()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.maxY))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.midX, y: rect.minY))
        return path
    }
}




struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}

[![enter image description here][1]][1]


https://i.stack.imgur.com/QFbuc.gif
```

Comment: What if you add the `currentIndex += 1` in the animation block?

Comment: @cedricbahirwe It didn't work